# Lxml html xpath context

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse a HTML file and I'd like to know how I can set the `context` of xpath search. What I mean is that I have a node element and want to make xpath search only inside this node as if it was the root one. For example, I have a form node and xpath search `//input` returns only inputs of the given form as opposed to all inputs of all forms on the page. How can I do this? I've found some `xpath context` docs [here](http://codespeak.net/lxml/extensions.html#the-xpath-context), but it doesn't seem to be quite what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

XPath expression `//input` will match all input elements, anywhere in your document, while `.//input` will match all inside current context.

Maybe if you improve your scenario description we can help you further.