# lxml HtmlElement xpath parses more than it should be able to

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Trying to parse HTML, I fail to loop through all `li` elements:

```
from lxml import html

page="<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>"
tree = html.fromstring(page)

for item in tree.xpath("//li"):
  print(html.tostring(item))
  print(item.xpath("//li/text()"))
```

I expect this output:

```
b'<li>one</li>'
['one']
b'<li>two</li>'
['two']
```

but I get this:

```
b'<li>one</li>'
['one', 'two']
b'<li>two</li>'
['one', 'two']
```

How is it possible that `xpath` can get both `li` elements' text from `item` in both iteration steps?

I can solve this using an counter as an index of course but I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: The question is an easy one, but +1 for clearly showing your code, your expected output, and your actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Lxml html xpath context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725268/lxml-html-xpath-context):

> XPath expression `//input` will match all input elements, anywhere in your document, while `.//input` will match all inside current context.

The solution is to use:

```
from lxml import html

page="<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>"
tree = html.fromstring(page)

for item in tree.xpath("//li"):
  print(html.tostring(item))
  print(item.xpath(".//text()")) #only changed line
```

Adding `.` before `//` prevents matching entire document and `li/` needs to be removed since you are "inside" the `li` tags already.

The output is:

```
b'<li>one</li>'
['one']
b'<li>two</li>'
['two']
```

Answer (score 1):

`item.xpath("//li/text()")` would search for all `li` elements in the entire tree. Since you want the text of the current node, you can just get the `text()`: `item.xpath("text()")`.

Or, even better, just get the [*text content*](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods):

```
for item in tree.xpath("//li"):
  print(html.tostring(item))
  print(item.text_content())
```

Comment: Thanks, after posting, I soon realized that a related question solves my core problem. I actually need the `li` elements in my real-world problem. The example was oversimplified.